# Can Adobe Flash Builder refactor->rename function, variables, class names and other objects like Java?

Tags: flash, flash-builder

FDT can do it, but half the time it times out and needs to be restarted on renaming some objects. Can Flash Builder do this?

Comment: FDT works fine for me when refactoring?

Comment: It definitely times out on some refactors, don't want to bash FDT, so I'll try to reproduce the behavior and post it sometime.

Answer (score 1):

It can indeed. In the code, select the class, function or variable reference and press Ctrl+Alt+R. In Flash Builder 4 you can also right-click and select *Source > Refactor* and in Flash Builder 4.5 *Refactor > Rename*.